# Understanding Scala code: (-_._2)

Tags: scala

Help me understand this Scala code:

```
sortBy(-_._2)
```

I understand that the first underscore (`_`) is a placeholder. I understand that `_2` means the second member of a Tuple.
But what does a minus (`-`) stand for in this code?

Comment: I think it has something to do with the `¯\_(ツ)_/¯` operator.

Comment: @LukasEder Curious about what this operator would do. :-)

Comment: @marcospereira: It is usually used to catch and ignore the `(╯°□°)╯︵ ┻━┻` exception

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Reverse order (i.e. descending), you sort by minus the second field of the tuple

The underscore is an anonymous parameter, so -_ is basically the same as x => -x

Some examples in plain scala:

```
scala> List(1,2,3).sortBy(-_)
res0: List[Int] = List(3, 2, 1)

scala> List("a"->1,"b"->2, "c"->3).sortBy(-_._2)
res1: List[(String, Int)] = List((c,3), (b,2), (a,1))

scala> List(1,2,3).sortBy(x => -x)
res2: List[Int] = List(3, 2, 1)
```

Answer (score 4):

Sort by sorts by `ascending` order as default. To inverse the order a `-` (Minus) can be prepended, as already explained by @TrustNoOne .

So `sortBy(-_._2)` sorts by the *second value* of a `Tuple2` but in reverse order.

A longer example:

```
scala> Map("a"->1,"b"->2, "c"->3).toList.sortBy(-_._2)
res1: List[(String, Int)] = List((c,3), (b,2), (a,1))
```

is the same as

```
scala> Map("a"->1,"b"->2, "c"->3).toList sortBy { case (key,value) => - value }
res1: List[(String, Int)] = List((c,3), (b,2), (a,1))
```